# How can i count every productID by using distinct and show it individually

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

Hello everyone i have a database with allot of different data with the same id that is showing multiple times. By using disctinct i can filter all data individually but now i want to count every productID individually.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT bim.product_id),  bim.component_id
FROM product_category AS bm
INNER JOIN products AS bim
ON bm.id = bim.ct_id
WHERE bm.id = 201
```

i get the following results

```
count(DISTINCT bim.component.id)   productID
"51"                                250174
```

but instead of this i wanna count how many times a product id is in the database.
like this

```
count(DISTINCT bim.component.id)   productID
    "42"                                250174
    "12"                                250173
    "14"                                250176
```

etc. Right now  it counts every productID in 1 column but i wanna count how many productIds there are for each product like the example above

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `Group BY`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT bim.component_id),  bim.product_id
FROM product_category AS bm INNER JOIN products AS bim ON bm.id = bim.ct_id
WHERE bm.id = 201
GROUP BY bim.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a `JOIN` is necessary.  This should do what you want:

```
SELECT bim.component_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT bim.product_id) 
FROM products bim
WHERE bim.ct_id = 201;
```